# Learning Redux Thunk. How to trigger action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk

I am learning Thunk and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Below I have two action creators. The first returns an object and the second returns a function (a "Thunk").

When the `doThing` action creator is invoked I expect one second to pass and for the action creator named `pingApiAction` to be invoked. As it stands this is not happening.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
export const pingApiAction = function(){
    console.log("ping")
    return {type:"PING"}
}



export function doThing() {
    console.log("works")
  return (dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(pingApiAction());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

Comment: So what *is* happening? Are you seeing `works` in the console? Can you show us where / how you're invoking the function call for `doThing`?

Answer (score 0):

from what i see, your problem is with your reducer and not your action or action creator.

So if you want your own code to be corrected, you can kindly paste your reducer or simply use the one i have written for you below:

```
//action creator
 const pingApiAction = function(){
    console.log("ping")
    return {type:"PING"}
}


//action creator
function doThing() {
    console.log("works")
  return (dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(pingApiAction());
    }, 1000);
  };
}

 
//reducer
const reducer =(state={ping:""},action)=>{
  
  switch(action.type){
    case "PING":
      return{...state,ping:"It works"}
        
        default:
        return state;
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);
console.log(store.getState());

store.dispatch({ type: 'PING' });
console.log(store.getState());
```